# How do you upload modified image directly to s3 bucket using python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, flask, python-imaging-library

I am trying to simply modify an image (resize it) that was uploaded via form then upload directly to s3 bucket. The example I am using below works when I keep the files local but I am having issue when trying to upload to s3.

```
 def _image_resize(temp_path, file, image_base, extension):
    image = Image.open(file)
    wpercent = (image_base / float(image.size[0]))
    hsize = int((float(image.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
    image = image.resize((image_base, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    modified_file_path = os.path.join(
        temp_path, file.filename + '.' + extension + '.png'
    )
    image.save(modified_file_path)
    with open(modified_file_path, 'rb') as data:
        upload_file_to_s3(data, Config.S3_BUCKET_NAME)
    return

def upload_file_to_s3(file, bucket_name, acl="public-read"):
        """
        Docs: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html
        """

        try:

            s3.upload_fileobj(
                file,
                bucket_name,
                ExtraArgs={
                    "ACL": acl
                }
            )

        except Exception as e:
            print("Something Happened: ", e)
            return e

        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `upload_fileobj` function for bytes date in `boto3` package as follows:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('mybucket')
obj = bucket.Object('mykey')

with open('filename', 'rb') as data:
    obj.upload_fileobj(data)
```

where you have to set the API keys such as AWS ACCESS KEY and SECRET KEY by using AWS CLI with `aws configure`.

Comment: Please see update functions. Still doesnt work for me.

Comment: you should give more info why isnt work and errors if it occurs. And upload file obj requires bytes type not a file. If you want to upload file then you need the upload_file.